# Should tf.Session() fall inside the context of tf.Graph()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I often see the following patterns in Tensorflow code, but frequently, I get better performance by ignoring them.

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():

    # Build graph here ...
    loss, train_op = ...

    with tf.Session() as sess: # OR: with sv.managed_sess() as sess, etc.

        # Run training steps here ...
        sess.run(train_op)
```

But I prefer to first define my graph and then separately run the session as follows (especially in Jupyter notebooks).

In one cell:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():

    # Build graph here ...
    loss, train_op = ...
```

In another cell:

```
with tf.Session() as sess: # OR: with sv.managed_sess() as sess, etc.

    # Run training steps here ...
    sess.run(train_op)
```

I've noticed it takes time to create the graph in the first approach. Sometimes I'm using multiple graphs and the second approach is my only option. Why would one approach be better than the other?

Comment: (if it's not clear, the main difference is the indentation of the `with` blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between these two approaches in a regular python script. However if you use notebooks, and execute cells separately then obviously not recreating graph is faster than making it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the second version. I am actually surprised it could work as is on your side. This

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  x = tf.zeros(())

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(x)
```

fails on my tensorflow 1.2.1 with a

```
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

If you are using a single graph, you can actually safely remove the `with tf.Graph().as_default():` line, because there *already* is a default graph by default. You do not need to create one extra. So this

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.zeros(())

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(x)
```

is perfectly legit and is preferable in my opinion.

Now if you are using more than one graph... well, generally you are better off with a single graph. You don't get any benefit from using multiple graphs. You should use them only when you have to.

Comment: I left out the details for clarity. Both examples work fine if you either specify which graph when creating a tf.Session, or use a tf.train.Supervisor together with a managed session (as shown in my question).

Comment: @awalllllll ok, makes sense. This does not affect the main message of my answer I think.